# Probability that one random variable is greater than or equal to another

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. with exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda = 1$ (the probability density functions $p_X (x) = e^{-x}$ and $p_Y (y) = e^{-x}$ in $[0, +\infty)$, $0$ otherwise). Find the cumulative distribution function, $F_Z (z) = P(Z \leq z)$, of the random variable $Z = \frac{X - Y}{X + Y}$.

The solution given to the problem starts off like this:

$$
P(Z \leq z) = P\left(\frac{X - Y}{X + Y} \leq z\right) = P((X + Y)z \geq X - Y) = P\left(Y \geq \frac{1 - z}{1 + z} X\right)
$$

So far, everything is clear to me. However, the next step is not. Namely, it says that:

$$
P\left(Y \geq \frac{1 - z}{1 + z} X\right) = \int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x} \left\{ \int\limits_{\frac{1 - z}{1 + z}x}^{+\infty} e^{-y}\, d y \right\} \, d x
$$

Where does this come from? I tried solving the problem "systematically," that is, by trying to find the probability density of $Z$ given the probability densities of $X$ and $Y$ (furthermore, since they're independent, we know that their joint density is the product of their marginal densities), and then integrating it, but could get nothing similar to the solution given.

When the integral given is solved (the process of solving it is clear to me), it comes out that $Z$ has uniform distribution from $-1$ to $1$.

**EDIT:** Okay, fixing a number for $z$ in $\displaystyle P\left(Y \geq \frac{1 - z}{1 + z} X\right)$ and plotting made the integral clear to me. I will try to solve this using my "traditional" method again and see if I made some mistakes previously. Do I delete this question?